# Dynamic drowndown using Ajax and PHP is showing blank

Tags: php, ajax

Below is my AJAX script used for dynamic multiselect.
The issue is it give blank option in my second drop down.
Can anyone plz help me to debug.
Also it worked in test when deployed to live its not functioning.
Any help will really help

```
<script>
function getmodels1(val) {
    alert(val.value);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_models.php",
    data:'compid='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#cname").html(data);
    }
    });
}
function selectCountry(val) {
$("#search-box").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
</script>
```

Below is my form

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Car Company</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">

<select onChange="getmodels1(this.value);"  name="ccompany" id="ccompany" class="form-control" >
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php $query =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblcompany");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['compid'];?>"><?php echo $row['CompanyName'];?></option>

<?php
}
?>
</select> </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Car Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">


<select name="cname" id="cname" class="form-control">
<option value="">Select</option>

</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Below is my getmdels PHP

```
  <?php
    include('includes/dbconnection.php');
    if(!empty($_POST["compid"])) 
    {
    $query =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmodels WHERE compid = '" . $_POST["compid"] . "'");
    ?>
    <option value="">Select Models</option>
    <?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))  
    {
    echo 'Success'
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"> <?php echo $row["models"];?></option>
    <?php
    }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Any console/php error?

Comment: Thank you . No error second drop down is blank. If you guide on steps to check any specific error will do the same

Comment: so if you open console after select no error ?

Comment: yes no error in console

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the getmodel.php file

`mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmodels WHERE compid = '" . $_POST["compid"] . "'");`

Instead of using '.' please use the PHP string interpolation so it will be easy for you to concatenate the string with PHP variables.

Try this,

```
`mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblmodels WHERE compid = '{$_POST["compid"]}'");`
```

And you are also displaying success which might cause a problem.

Comment: That is _not_ where the problem lies. (And with a simple test like `$_POST["compid"] = 'foo'; echo "SELECT * FROM tblmodels WHERE compid = '" . $_POST["compid"] . "'";` you could have verified that, before giving a misleading answer.)

Comment: @ Sujan . - Tried with your suggestion. But no luck . Btw removed success . Thanks

Comment: @CBroe - Can you plz give insight on how to check whether AJAX URL control is going or not

Answer (score 0):

@Nischal

> In *`get_models.php`* You are just looping the option inside while.
>   Instead of the line *`<option value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"> <?php echo $row["models"];?></option>` add echo statement `echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["models"].'</option>';`*

*Don't forget to remove `echo 'Success'` message there.*

Comment: Removed 'Success'. Above solution also dint work. If you help to check/debug whether Ajax call is happening or not that would be helpful.  Can I put any alert message to check whether Ajax URL is working or not.

Comment: open networks tab in console. and trigger one change ...check the server side response